# How to migrate Magento-1 to PHP7

Tags: magento-1, php-7

I have struggled with this error after installing php7 in my PC.also I googling and found some answer but this is not a standard way to do this.because when I upload this source on the server isn't it create a problem because server PHP version is lower.

I have found a solution like below.

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Is there any other way to out of this situation without touching core file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PHP related question and not Magento itself.

Comment: this is not php related as we are suffering in magento due to php.

Comment: I suggest to change the title of your question to: "How to migrate Magento to PHP7" then. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> because when i upload this source on the server isn't it create problem because server php version is lower.

No, the PHP 7 compatible code works on PHP 5, too.

I can recommend the [Inchoo_PHP7](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/) extension for Magento CE 1.9.3. It also has branches for CE 1.9.2 and EE.

The extension fixes all known incompatibilities without changing core files.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is related to PHP itself, but if your question is: "How to migrate Magento 1.x to PHP7", then the answer is:

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7

Here you have a patch for Magento 1.x to make it working with PHP7.

Answer (score 1):

As already told here by the other answers, the Extension from [Inchoo](https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/) makes magento 1 php 7 compatible.

But in your case, I recommand that instead of making you magento work under php 7 on your pc and php5 on your server, that you either install php5 on your pc (you can even install it parallel to php 7.0 on most operating systems, or that you upgrade your server version (php 7.0 give a nice performance boost over php 5.6 but don't bother with php 7.1)